# AWK to replace character for lines not starting with ">"

Tags: text-processing, awk, bioinformatics

I'm working with sequence data and I stupidly cannot find the correct way to replace "`.`" by "`X`" in lines not starting with "`>`" using awk. I really need to use awk and not sed.

I got this far, but simply all "." are replaced in this way:

```
awk '/^>/ {next} {gsub(/\./,"X")}1' Sfr.pep > Sfr2.pep
```

Example subdata:

```
>sequence.1
GTCAGTCAGTCA.GTCAGTCA
```

Result I want to get:

```
>sequence.1
GTCAGTCAGTCAXGTCAGTCA
```

Answer (score 11, accepted):

It seems more natural to do this with `sed`:

```
sed '/^>/!y/./X/' Sfr.pep >Sfr2.pep
```

This would match `^>` against the current line ("does this line start with a `>` character?").  If that expression does *not* match, the `y` command is used to change each dot in that line to `X`.

Testing:

```
$ cat Sfr.pep
>sequence.1
GTCAGTCAGTCA.GTCAGTCA
```

```
$ sed '/^>/!y/./X/' Sfr.pep >Sfr2.pep
```

```
$ cat Sfr2.pep
>sequence.1
GTCAGTCAGTCAXGTCAGTCA
```

---

The main issue with your `awk` code is that `next` is executed whenever you come across a fasta header line.  This means that you code only produces sequence data, without headers.  That sequence data should look ok though, but that would not be much help.

Simply negating the test and dropping the `next` block (or preceding the `next` with `print`) would solve it in `awk` for you, but, and this is my personal opinion, using the `y` command in `sed` is more elegant than using `gsub()` (or `s///g` in `sed`) for transliterating single characters.

Comment: The reason why I would like to try with AWK specifically is because I tried it with sed before: { sed -e '/^>/!s/\./X/' }
And although this worked for most of the files, two did not get edited. However, with your sed code it worked! Thanks!

Comment: @TUnix That's because you lack the `/g` at the end of the `s` command. Your `sed` approach would only replace the _first_ dot on each line, as if you had used `sub()` in place of `gsub()` in `awk`.

Answer (score 9):

You can try with:

```
awk '!/^>/ { gsub(/\./, "X") }1' Sfr.pep > Sfr2.pep
```

Output:

```
>sequence.1
GTCAGTCAGTCAXGTCAGTCA
```

Answer (score 2):

You're not printing the lines that begin with `>`, you're only printing the lines that you perform the substitution in. Use the `print` command to print before skipping to the next line.

```
awk '/^>/ {print;next} {gsub(/\./,"X")}1' Sfr.pep > Sfr2.pep
```

Answer (score 0):

**Using Raku (née Perl_6), and/or Perl:**

```
raku -pe 's:g/^^ <-[>]>  <-[.]>*?  <(\.)> /X/;'
```

OR (maybe more readable):

```
raku -pe 's:g{ ^^ <-[>]>  <-[.]>*?  <(\.)> } = Q{X};'
```

Raku is called at the shell command line with the `-pe` autoprint flags. The `s///` in-place substitution operator is used here, in two guises. The first is the classic while the second is Raku's update to the Perl(5) `s{...}{...};` idiom.

Briefly, reading the atoms left-to-right, *"search starting from the `^^` start-of-line and where `<-[>]>` no ">" individual character is found, then where `<-[.]>*?` non-greedily no literal zero-or-more "." are found, if a `<(\.)>` literal "." is then found, drop all matches before/after and replace these "." with "X"; do this globally, linewise, autoprinting all lines with the substitution(s) as described."*

Speaking of the Perl5 lineage, here's how you would do the `P5` cognate to the second Raku example above (but the `-pE` command line flag might be better on older installs):

```
perl -pe 's{^ [^>]  [^.]*?  \K\. }{X}gx;'
```

(Special thanks to @Sinan Ünür for P5 guidance, link below).

https://stackoverflow.com/a/15578028/7270649
https://stackoverflow.com/a/24542792/7270649
https://docs.raku.org/language/operators#s///_in-place_substitution
https://raku.org/

Answer (score 0):

```
#!/usr/bin/python
import re
g=re.compile(r'^>')
rep=re.compile(r'\.')
k=open('file','r')
for b in k:
    if not re.search(g,b):
        er=re.sub(rep,"X",b)
        print er.strip()
    else:
        print b.strip()
```

output

```
>sequence.1
GTCAGTCAGTCAXGTCAGTCA
```